# vectorize a complex for-loop and enhance the speed in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, matrix, sapply

Hi I am trying to speed up the calculation of the following for loop by vectorising it, i.e. using `sapply()`, etc.

But it seems to be a mission impossible due to the very complicated structure. I am been trying for a few days but end up with no solution.

Could anyone take a look on how to speed up the following function??

```
alpha2f <- function(p0,t2,n1,n2){
  alpha2=0
  for (x1 in 12:n1){    
    for (x2 in 0:n2){    
      for (y2 in 0:n2){
        a=dbinom(x1,n1,p0)
        b=dbinom(x2,n2,p0)
        alpha2=alpha2+a*b*dbinom(y2,n2,p0)*ifelse(ztest(x1+x2,y2,n1+n2,n2)>t2,1,0)
      }}}
  return(alpha2)
}
```

Comment: Questions such as this should have a description of what the code is trying to do, as well as the attempt on which improvement is desired.

Comment: I've tried to copy/paste your function, but got `Error in ifelse(ztest(x1 + x2, y2, n1 + n2, n2) > t2, 1, 0) : could not find function "ztest"`. It is difficult to help if we don't have working example or at least description what the function does.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably faster your code by vectorizing it and removing unnecessary things such as the ifelse. You should try :

```
alpha2f <- function(p0, t2, n1, n2){
  alls <- expand.grid(x1=12:n1, x2=0:n2, y2=0:n2)
  a <- dbinom(alls$x1, n1, p0)
  b <- dbinom(alls$x2, n2, p0)
  z <- numeric(nrow(alls))
  X <- alls$x1+alls$x2
  N <- n1+n2
  for (i in 1:length(z))
   z[i] <- (ztest(X[i], alls$y2|i], N, n2) > t2)
  d <- dbinom(alls$y2,n2,p0)
  alpha2 <- sum(a*b*d*z)
  return(alpha2)
  }
```

I was not able to test it because I didn't know which ztest function you used. If this function is vectorized then you don't need the loop.
HTH